# Effect of using page-able memory for asynchronous memory copy?

Tags: asynchronous, cuda

In CUDA C Best Practices Guide Version 5.0, Section 6.1.2, it is written that:

> In contrast with cudaMemcpy(), the asynchronous transfer version
>   requires pinned host memory (see Pinned Memory), and it contains an
>   additional argument, a stream ID.

It means the `cudaMemcpyAsync` function should fail if I use simple memory.

But this is not what happened.

Just for testing purpose, I tried the following program:

## Kernel:

```
__global__ void kernel_increment(float* src, float* dst, int n)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if(tid<n)   
        dst[tid] = src[tid] + 1.0f;
}
```

## Main:

```
int main()
{
    float *hPtr1, *hPtr2, *dPtr1, *dPtr2;

    const int n = 1000;

    size_t bytes = n * sizeof(float);

    cudaStream_t str1, str2;

    hPtr1 = new float[n];
    hPtr2 = new float[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        hPtr1[i] = static_cast<float>(i);

    cudaMalloc<float>(&dPtr1,bytes);
    cudaMalloc<float>(&dPtr2,bytes);

    dim3 block(16);
    dim3 grid((n + block.x - 1)/block.x);

    cudaStreamCreate(&str1);
    cudaStreamCreate(&str2);

    cudaMemcpyAsync(dPtr1,hPtr1,bytes,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,str1);
    kernel_increment<<<grid,block,0,str2>>>(dPtr1,dPtr2,n);
    cudaMemcpyAsync(hPtr2,dPtr2,bytes,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,str1);

    printf("Status: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    printf("Status: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

    cudaStreamDestroy(str1);
    cudaStreamDestroy(str2);

    cudaFree(dPtr1);
    cudaFree(dPtr2);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        std::cout<<hPtr2[i]<<std::endl;

    delete[] hPtr1;
    delete[] hPtr2;

    return 0;
}
```

The program gave correct output. The array incremented successfully.

How did `cudaMemcpyAsync` execute without page locked memory?
Am I missing something here?

Comment: @NolwennLeGuen... actually it has been a requirement since the beginning. I have read this in previous CUDA guides as well.

Comment: The documentation for the function states _This function exhibits asynchronous behavior for most use cases._. If pageable memory is used then the driver has to copy the memory to a non-pageable buffer. If the transfer size is greater than the driver's non-pageable buffer then the driver waits for the non-pageable buffer to be available to complete the rest of the transfer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`cudaMemcpyAsync` is fundamentally an asynchronous version of `cudaMemcpy`. This means that it doesn't block the calling host thread when the copy call is issued. That is the basic behaviour of the call.

*Optionally*, if the call is launched into the non default stream, and if the host memory is a pinned allocation, and the device has a free DMA copy engine, the copy operation can happen while the GPU simultaneously performs another operation: either kernel execution or another copy (in the case of a GPU with two DMA copy engines). If any of these conditions are not satisfied, the operation *on the GPU* is functionally identical to a standard `cudaMemcpy` call, ie. it serialises operations on the GPU, and no simultaneous copy-kernel execution or simultaneous multiple copies can occur. The only difference is that the operation doesn't block the calling host thread.

In your example code, the host source and destination memory are not pinned. So the memory transfer cannot overlap with kernel execution (ie. they serialise operations on the GPU). The *calls* are still asynchronous on the host. So what you have is functionally equivalent to:

```
cudaMemcpy(dPtr1,hPtr1,bytes,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
kernel_increment<<<grid,block>>>(dPtr1,dPtr2,n);
cudaMemcpy(hPtr2,dPtr2,bytes,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

with the exception that all the calls are asynchronous on the host, so the host thread blocks at the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` call rather than at each of the memory transfer calls.

This is absolutely expected behaviour.

Comment: What happens if all those conditions *are* satisfied? Will the kernel produce incorrect results because all the memory hasn't been copied to the device?

Comment: Pretty sure @talonmies means "if _any_ of the conditions are not satisfied..."